# Convert arithmetic returns to log returns

Tags: returns, log-returns

I have a series of arithmetic returns and I need log returns.  I do not have the underlying prices.  How do I convert?

All the posts I have found explain why using one versus the other is appropriate but how do I get from one to the other without the underlying data?

Thanks

Comment: Arithmetic returns is $a_t = S_t/S_{t-1}-1$. Log-return is $r_t = \ln(S_t/S_{t-1})$. So $r_t = \ln(a_t+1)$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transmuting one to the other is pretty straightforward without the underlying sequence of prices.

To go from **log to simple**:

$R = exp(r) - 1$

To go from **simple to log**:

$r = log(R+1)$